# Test exceeded execution timeout period

Tags: c#, unit-testing

My main.cs code:

```
 public string Generate(int length)
 {
     char[] chars = "$%#@!*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890?;:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^&".ToCharArray();
     string password = string.Empty;
     Random random = new Random();

     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
     {
         int x = random.Next(1, chars.Length);

         if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
             password += chars.GetValue(x);
         else
             i--;
     }
     return password;
 }
```

I have make a test code

```
[TestMethod]
[Timeout(1000)]
public void RenderingPasswordShouldHaveMaximumSize()
{
    var amountOfCharacters = Int32.MaxValue;
    var generator = new PasswordGenerator();
    var target = generator.Generate(amountOfCharacters);

    Assert.Fail("This method should throw an exception if you try to create a password with too many characters");
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Message: Test 'RenderingPasswordShouldHaveMaximumSize' exceeded execution timeout period

Can someone help me with this? My password needs to have a max size of 74.

Comment: Your `Generate` method is taking too long to generate a password, one would suspect.

Comment: you *could* try to debug through your code and experience what happens

Comment: As a warning, do not deface your questions. If you do this again, we will lock them and suspend your account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just noticed you actually want your test to take a long time, ignore the part about `Int32.MaxValue`.

Your loop is a little strange, you're decrementing the iterator in order to try and utilise all of the letters, but that can cause problems. It's not a case of it taking too long, but of it not really generating a password properly.

I would fix *your version* like this:

```
static string Generate(int length)
{
    // also, seed your random so you don't get the same password
    Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    char[] chars = "$%#@!*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890?;:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^&".ToCharArray();
    string password = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        int x = random.Next(0, chars.Length);

        if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
            password += chars.GetValue(x);
        else
            i--;
    }

    if (length < password.Length) password = password.Substring(0, length);
    return password;
}
```

I've tested this and it works:

Test code:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Generate(5));
Thread.Sleep(50);

Debug.WriteLine(Generate(10));
Thread.Sleep(50);

Debug.WriteLine(Generate(20));
Thread.Sleep(50);

Debug.WriteLine(Generate(30));
Thread.Sleep(50);

Debug.WriteLine(Generate(40));
Thread.Sleep(50);

Debug.WriteLine(Generate(60));
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

And results:

```
SDxF0
i8ZLhm1gxn
@0Ldn7I&1:Kg2x3SYE;m
U?5uO%N4hkpq1*y;9SRVaer^Eij:bT
nvL;E3#D1MQgTicSdojHOwz:VFk2x&94a*PZ@X80
cSm39n:%1sL*lk2B?yVDTPZCA0vGb@udjeW5KoUw6qRNxY^pazH$JXiQ;tFg
```

Also, bear in mind that the way you are adding characters to the password, you're making it so that it utilises all characters in the `char[]` but has no repeats. What this means is that the max length of your password is equal to the length of your `char[]`.

I would recommend something like this:

```
static string Generate(int length)
{
    Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int x = random.Next(33, 123);
        sb.Append((char)x);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Which gives the same results, but can also handle longer lengths, such as 200:

```
t5[5l
WoEZG;8^9<
6(4Q*Y7k>`?ohte6F^pe
DVb\5l^JMKc`q&[#$U4Kq^\OW`JrRi
#iQSq0\WRoDe<]k36nOhNOb-#"Zt!cK8iaR.I>VF
1<%^"B)6bZhWEiazmfmO7Vv*Rw]TbKV+GRJUc%k23Lq/HC.I6Eha6!5V@v-&
jOnV_`(Cf$I\kFr/%%/loG"bx9lV1E?`[A"y1)pF5tA".x?**(E/>kzCN-XGnL2B`c!JEtxw0cXu'zTztcM*z0CkBYK%LIRcbz<Fxo`0*HzU4&=NTXM,z)CP@1)fJtKa2o3'_/#&#=zR1iW<<wLnwFdYXg&hgta0x:C?m6jEVH*])k@QTgKMIXdg,UJr*59)VkUrG8J&
```

Comment: See my latest update, you had a flaw in your loop. The length of the password should be decided afterwards, and the loop should use the length of the char array, not of the desired password.

Comment: I need a maximum length of 74 when i want to create a password longer than 74 he needs to give me a fail message that it's not possible

Comment: `if (length > 74) throw new ArgumentException("length");` maybe something like this?

Answer (score 1):

What about just adding this:

```
if (length > chars.Length) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Password too long", length);
}
```

On your test, you can check that this `Exception` is thrown as expected.

Your code will **never** finish unless you pass a number less than `74`.

Acording to your code, if the randomly selected character is already in the password, you just iterage again (decreasing `i`).

Have you thought what will happen once you have used all the characters of `chars`?

Comment: +1, nicely spotted. My suggestion though, allow a character to be in the password more than once.. :)

Comment: I would also recommend that, however, if OP wants no repeating characters then it is still possible.